# how to index and search phrase query with special characters in lucene.net?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I tried to search multiple words and special characters like "Engineering & Construction" using phrasequery and added in to boolean query but its not getting any result.The way i'm indexing the query is

```
doc.Add(new Field("Industry","Engineering & Construction", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
```

For Searching:

```
var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
PhraseQuery phrasequery = new PhraseQuery();
phrasequery.Add(new Term("Industry","Engineering & Construction"));
booleanQuery.Add(phraseQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

the booleanQuery contains {+Industry:"Engineering & Construction"} even though its not getting desired result.

Comment: What analyzer are you using?

Comment: I'm using StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29) @goalie7960

Comment: I know StandardAnalyzer will strip out the "&" symbol. Do you even need to analyze the input or will you always have the full/beginning part of the phrase to search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Indexing :

```
doc.Add(new Field("Industry","Engineering & Construction", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
```

For Searching :

```
TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("Industry", "Engineering & Construction"));
booleanQuery.Add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

It was helpful for my criteria.It searches the exact phrase with special characters.

Comment: Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED would also mean that you can't search for this field with "free" text as the words engineering or construction since it will only work for exact match. So not a good option if the input is user input from ie. a textbox since the user have to get upper/lower case right to get a match.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
phrasequery.Add(new Term("Industry","Engineering & Construction"));
```

Produces a single term, `Engineering  & Construction`, but the index will have two terms, `engineering` and `construction`, in sequence (the `&` will be removed by the analyzer).  Constructing a phrasequery manually like this requires you to understand the tokens, and add each term separately, like:

```
phrasequery.Add(new Term("Industry","engineering"));
phrasequery.Add(new Term("Industry","construction"));
```

Of course, the easier way is to use a query parser;

```
Query phraseQuery = queryparser.parse("Industry:Engineering & Construction");
booleanquery.add(phraseQuery);
```

Comment: I'm using ` Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);
            QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "", analyzer);` .The querparser result was {+(Industry:engineering construction)}.it eliminates the special character. @femtoRgon

Comment: I need to search exact phrase including the special characters.@goalie7960

Comment: If you need the special character maintained, you are using the wrong Analyzer.  Use [KeywordAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/KeywordAnalyzer.html).

Comment: By using WildcardQuery and setting Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED  for indexing, its working perfectly for my criteria.This link could be useful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165488/lucene-net-and-partial-starts-with-phrase-search?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Yes, using `NOT_ANALYZED` will work as well, though if you want an exact match, you should use a `TermQuery` instead of `WildcardQuery`.  Using a `WildcardQuery` to acquire an exact match doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you @femtoRgon.By changing KeywordAnalyzer,the phrase query works perfectly.